fetch API with PUT method gives error 419
I've been using the fetch API for a long time with POST like so:
let _token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content;
let form = document.getElementById("my-form");
let formData = new FormData(form);
formData.append("_token", _token);
fetch("/upload", {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData,
})
.then((response) => {
})

And in my web.php the route is:
Route::post('/upload', [MyController::class, 'upload']);

Now, I wanted to test it with PUT instead, so I changed the route method in web.php:
Route::put('/upload', [MyController::class, 'upload']);

And changed the fetch method:
fetch("/upload", {
    method: "PUT",
    body: formData,
})
.then((response) => {
})

So I simply replaced the word post with put, but now I get error 419 (Page Expired) as if I don't have a token. Why?
